# Regex add string after 11th instance of /

Tags: regex

I have a collection of web addresses with the following structure:

`https://www.example.com/img/public/vendor1/us/en/product-assets/vendor/product/green/device_230x400_a.gif`

When constructing this data structure, I realized that I needed to add `/image/` after the given product name. The product names will vary, but the slashes are fixed instances, so this should be appropriate: add `/image/` after the 11th instance of `/`.

In other words, aim for:

`https://www.example.com/img/public/vendor1/us/en/product-assets/vendor/product/image/green/device_230x400_a.gif`

I would greatly appreciate any assistance; I am using Notepad++ for replacing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^(https?://(?:[^/]+/){9})(.*)$
Replace: $1image/$2
```

This regex says to:

```regex
^
(                     capture in $1
    https?:           http: or https:
    //                //
    (?:[^\/]+\/){9}   match 9 path components
)
(.*)                  capture the remainder of the URL in $2
$
```

Then we replace with `$1image/$2` to insert an `/image` path component at the desired location.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZTGkiF/2).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation; I wasn't capturing the remainder (.*). Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the match of the regular expression

```
(?:.*?\/){11}
```

with `$0 + 'image/'`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MXiDGN/1)

`$0` holds the match.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?:    # begin non-capture group
  .*?  # match zero or more characters, as few as possible (lazily)
  \/   # match '/'
){11}  # end non-capture group and execute it 11 times
```